# Difference between angular 4 and 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

Are there any features in Angular 4 that are now obsolete in Angular 6?
Or in other words can I use angular 6 library in my application and use all of Angular 4 functionalities in it.
I'm new to Angular framework and just wondering should I start with Angular 6 directly or should I first read Angular 4.

Comment: It largely depends on the library itself. Angular 6 uses `rxjs 6`, which is a major (incompatible) change. You may check what is different between angular 4 and 5, then 5 and 6.

Comment: You can use https://update.angular.io/ . Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You can check the changes between versions on https://update.angular.io/

Comment: @CataJohn Haha, GMTA

Comment: @Roy Haha, at the exact same time as well:D

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the functionalities that your app has. The differences from Angular 2 to Angular 6 are very small, the main difference was made between Angular 1 or now known as AngularJS and the new Angular (2-6). The differences between all Angular versions are insignificant to the general developer, as they are very small, or there are new ways of doing things, but 99% of the old ones also work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there differences of deprecated classes/methods..etc and new ones replacing them. You do NOT need to start with Angular 4 since 6 is not that different except the upgrade like the HTTPClient API for example. If you want to know the difference between version 4.0 (first 4) and version 6.1 (latest 6 at this time) then go to the official upgrade site

https://update.angular.io

and select the versions and `Advanced` and see the changes needed on any app running on 4. Most notable change is rxjs 6. Also, the old APIs still work by the way.